# horizontal scroll with 100% width on grid cell

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to have a css grid, inside each cell of the grid, I want a title with a maximum size of 100% of the width of the cell. If title is too long, i want to scroll.

This is how it looks currently with the correct scrolling behavior but with a fixed width on the long title. Instead of a fixed width, i want a width of 100% of the cell width (so the grey block should be as long as red box)

codePen: https://codepen.io/vincent2303/pen/ExwZEpW

[image: screenshot]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 800px;
  gap: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  height: 30vh;
}

.title-wrapper {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class=grid>

  <div>
    <div class="title-wrapper">
      <h2>long title, i can scroll---------</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Short title</h2>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea to do that ?

NOTE: To make the code example simple, the `.grid` class has a width of `800px` but in reality, it's width is defined by its parent on which i can not predict the width (i'm working on a react app and this code will implement a component used in multiple places with different sizes).

Comment: do you think making the red boxes bigger by the height of the grey box, than using the 100% width of the red box as the max width of the gray box and overlapping the red box with the gray one with "z-index" would be acceptable?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can not use max width because i do not know the width of the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your grid potentially contains overflowing content, you cannot work with `1fr`, here's why:

- `1fr` is just short for `minmax(auto, 1fr)`.
- `minmax(a, b)` becomes **`a`** (without any minmax) when `a >= b` is `true`.
- So in your case your grid behaves as if you had defined it as `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;`, because `auto` is larger than `1fr` for your first column.

To fix that, you need to tell your grid that it isn't allowed to extend the cells when content becomes too wide.

Use `minmax(0, 1fr)` instead of `1fr`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  width: 800px;
  gap: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  height: 30vh;
}

h2 {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class=grid>

  <div>
    <h2>long title, i can scroll------------------ - - - - ----</h2>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Short title</h2>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much ! I didn't know fr unit was working like that (i thought if was just a percentage).

Comment: I just accepted your solution.
I tried to upvote your solution but i don't have enough reputation to do so.
Thank you again :)

Comment: Insight and solution all-in-one. Thank you!

Comment: I don’t understand why it works, but this does indeed work. Here’s someone else’s somewhat unsatisfying description: https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/

Answer (score 0):

As commented heres a possibility:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 800px;
  gap: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  height: 50vh;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.title-wrapper {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class=grid >

    <div>
    

      <div class="box" >
          <div class="title-wrapper" >
        <h2>long title, i can scroll---------------------------------</h2>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
    
      <div class="box" >
          <h2>Short title</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, I can't use max-width box because i do not know the width of the boxes.
In the given example, the width of the grid is 800px but in reality it is determined by the parent width.

Comment: it still should be working. The whidth of the gray box is just 100% of the width of thered box so changing the width of the red box will influence the width of the gray box. i used max width just to test the possibility of scrolling when the red box has an given width

Comment: If I remove the max-width property on the box class, it changes the shape of the gird (the left column become much larger than the second one).
codePen: https://codepen.io/vincent2303/pen/NWadYXm

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be hard without JavaScript, Dev his answers works, but it involves a fixed max-width.

I've got a solution with JavaScript that seems to work.

```js
    /* Execute when the DOM is loaded, because otherwise the HTML elements might nog be in the DOM. */
    window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        generateGridItemsWidthVariable()

    } )

    /* Execute when the window is resized, because the width of the boxes might change. */
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', () => {

        generateGridItemsWidthVariable()

    } )

    /* Generate the variable for the grid items. */
    function generateGridItemsWidthVariable() {

        /* Select all the grid items and create an array to loop trough. */
        let gridItems = Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName( 'grid__item' ) )

        /* Loop trough the grid items. */
        gridItems.forEach( gridItem => {

            /* Reset the grid item width, because otherwise the item won't resize. */
            gridItem.style.setProperty( '--grid-item--width', '' )

            /* Get the width of the grid item. */
            let gridItemWidth = gridItem.clientWidth.toString()
            /* Set the width of the grid item as a CSS variable. */
            gridItem.style.setProperty( '--grid-item--width', gridItemWidth + 'px' )

        } )

    }
```

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        padding: 50px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 2em;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 800px;
        gap: 20px;
    }

    .grid__item {
        --grid-item--width: 10px;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: #e74c3c;
        height: 30vh;
    }

    .title-wrapper {
        background-color: #bdc3c7;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .title-wrapper h2 {
        max-width: var(--grid-item--width);
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<div class=grid >

    <div class="grid__item">
        <div class="title-wrapper" >
            <h2>long title, i can scroll-----------------------</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="box" ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid__item">
        <h2>Short title</h2>
        <div class="box" ></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Unfortunately, i'm working on react app and i think the use of javascript to manipulate DOM elements is something i should avoid.

Comment: Ah, got it @VinceM. Do you have to use `grid` or is all CSS usable?

Comment: All css is usable. But What i am trying to build is a complex grid, I think using flexbox for instance would be quite hard. Here is an image example of grid i'm trying to build: https://sparkbox.com/uploads/article_uploads/cssgrid_flexbox_fallbacks.png

Comment: Grid is the perfect solution here. No JS needed. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Well `1fr` resolves to `minmax(auto, 1fr)` and this means that  the minimum width of the grid column is `min-content`, that is more then `1fr`. There is a quick solution to this issue  just replacing `1fr` by `minmax(0px, 1fr)`, by this, parent's width is devided between 2 columns, and this way you have the scroll bar as you wish.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  height: 30vh;
}

h2 {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class=grid>

  <div>
    <h2>long title, i can scroll----------------------------</h2>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Short title</h2>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```